# Probability of system failure question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having trouble answering these questions and understanding the answers to these questions.
[image]

The definition of conditional probability $P[A|B] = \frac{P[A \cap B]}{Pr[B]}$

(a) Let $P[B]$ be that exactly five links have failed. Let $P[A]$ be that A can still communicate with B. I first started by looking at all the paths between A and B that have less than 5 links, which gives adg and bch. So, I know that the probability of $P[A \cap B]$ is $2$. But I'm having trouble coming up with $P[B]$. I know that out of $8$ links, there $8 \choose{5}$ distinct ways that the links could go down. The answer in the book is $\frac{2}{8 \choose 5}$ but I'm having trouble believing that $8 \choose{5}$ is the $P[B]$ since it just specifies the "number of ways" 5 out of 8 links could be down.

(b) Let $P[B]$ be that exactly 5 links that have failed. Let $P[A]$ be that $g$ is up and $h$ is down. Because the same is true for the other way around. Assuming that $P[B]$ is the same as the one in (a) (which I still don't get), we can say $P[B] = {8\choose{5}}$ (or can we?). If 5 out of 8 links are definitely down, then there are 3 links that could be up. After this  I'm not sure where to go.

(c) The only path from A to B not involving a,d,h is becfg. Since each link has a probability of failure $p$, their probability of success is $1-p$. The probability of all 4 of those links being up is $(1-p)^4$. This one I fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other paths with less than five links, like adfh, but that is not important.  If five links fail only three are working.  The only three link paths are adg and bch.  For a, compute the number of sets of five that could fail and the chance A can communicate with B is two out of this.  For b you choose one of g or h to fail and four of the remaining to fail out of all the selections of five to fail.  For c you need bdfg all to work and don't care about e.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm starting to get it. For a) and b) do we just ignore the conditional probability formula completely? I can't find a way to express these problems in terms of $P[A]$, $P[B]$, and $P[A \cap B]$. Furthermore, for b) - if all 5 out of 8 links fail, and one more (either g or h) fail, there's 6 failures and only 2 remaining - where did "four of the remaining" come from? The answer in my book is $\frac{6 \choose 4}{8 \choose 5}$

Comment: Do you mind clarifying the above ?

Comment: For b your book has lost a factor $2 \choose 1$ to choose which of g and h has failed.  The $6 \choose 4$ is the number of ways to choose four of the other six to fail.  Those are independent choices, so you multiply them.

Comment: Hmm now I'm even more confused (thanks for sticking with me) - First of all $4 \cdot 2 \choose 1 \neq 6 \choose 4$ and why do we want four of the other six to fail ?

Comment: Ah okay so now I understand where the 4 is coming from since we are setting one of the 5 to be a g or h failure and choosing which of the *rest* fail. But why are we choosing from 6 again? I know 8-2=6 but I can't seem to justify why that works

Comment: Because there are six choices that are neither g nor h.  Sorry for the last, I got confused.  The chance is $\frac {{2 \choose 1}{6 \choose 4}}{8 \choose 5}$.  This is in agreement with the last one of my comments that I have not deleted.

Comment: Great thanks I get it now! So there's not really a way to apply the conditional probability formula I provided earlier? My book doesn't use it either but it's strange that this is a question provided in the same chapter